# CSS code for making tables look similar to those in Google Drive

Tags: html, css, html-table

I really like the way tables have been designed in the popup boxes that are used in Google Drive. I need a similar clean and refreshing design for my tables which have significant amount of content. Below is what I want:[image]

I can do the HTML, I need the CSS code and guidelines for getting the row separators as shown in the fig above. Observe that the line under Counts is a darker shade of gray than those used to separate the rows. How can I achieve this effect and how do I add row separators? Please help!

Comment: You can right click that pop-up ang "Inspect Element" if your in Chrome to see the styles applied to that table. (the same feature is also available in other browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle where I've attempted to recreate that look by sight. Mostly it's just separating the styles for `th` from those for `td`. Thanks for the question, this was good practice.

http://jsfiddle.net/mecBe/2/